# Javascript writing table multiple times by one function

Tags: javascript, html-table

I am trying to learn js and I decided to create some simply game circle of crosses.
Here is code :

(JS)

```
var tab = [[0,0,0],[0,0,0],[0,0,0]];
var x = 0;
var y = 0;
var xz = 0;
var yz = tab[0].length - 1;
var xu = 1;
var yu = 1;
var val = '';
var gd = 0;
var body = document.body;
var div = document.getElementById("content");
var tbl = document.createElement('table');
tbl.border = '1px';
tbl.style.width = '75px';
div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Actually chosen coordinates: ' + xu + ',' + yu); //Easter egg for smartest- why Quokka plugin in VS Code is returning '​​Cannot read property 'insertAdjacentHTML' of null'. When none of things used in this line is null. :)

function go() {
    //if (tab[xu][yu] == 0) {
        //system to secure writing on already used cells
        get();
        var yu = 1;
        var xu = 1;
    //} else {
        //div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'This cell is used.');
    //}
    draw();
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var xz = 0;
    var yz = tab[0].length - 1;
    var val = '';
}

function get() {
    tab[xu][yu] = 2;
    if(gd < 5){
        do{
            x = Math.floor(Math.random()*tab.length);
            y = Math.floor(Math.random()*tab[0].length);
        }while(tab[x][y]!=0)
        gd++;
        tab[x][y] = 1;
    }else{
        document.write('<h3>GAME OVER</h3>');
    }
}

function draw() {
    div.innerHTML = '<p>Remember U are X.</p>';
    while (xz < tab.length) {
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        while (yz >= 0) {
            switch (tab[xz][yz]) {
                case 0:
                    val = '.';
                    break;

                case 1:
                    val = 'O';
                    break;

                case 2:
                    val = 'X';
                    break;
            }
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
            yz--;
        }
        yz = tab[0].length - 1;
        xz++;
    }
    div.appendChild(tbl);
    div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Actually chosen coordinates: ' + xu + ',' + yu);
}


function drawt() {
    div.innerHTML = '<p>Remember U are X.</p>';
    while (xz < tab.length) {
        var tr = tbl.insertRow();
        while (yz >= 0) {
            switch (tab[xz][yz]) {
                case 0:
                    val = '.';
                    break;

                case 1:
                    val = 'O';
                    break;

                case 2:
                    val = 'X';
                    break;
            }
            var td = tr.insertCell();
            td.appendChild(document.createTextNode(val));
            yz--;
        }
        yz = tab[0].length - 1;
        xz++;
    }
    div.appendChild(tbl);
    div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Actually chosen coordinates: ' + xu + ',' + yu);
}



function Right() {
    if (xu < 2) {
        xu++;
    } else {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Nope');
    }
    draw();
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var xz = 0;
    var yz = tab[0].length - 1;
    var val = '';
}


function Left() {
    if (xu > 0) {
        xu--;
    } else {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Nope');
    }
    draw();
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var xz = 0;
    var yz = tab[0].length - 1;
    var val = '';
}


function Up() {
    if (yu < 2) {
        yu++;
    } else {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Nope');
    }
    draw();
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var xz = 0;
    var yz = tab[0].length - 1;
    var val = '';
}


function Down() {
    if(yu > 0){
        yu--;
    } else {
        div.insertAdjacentHTML('beforeend', 'Nope');
    }
    draw();
    var x = 0;
    var y = 0;
    var xz = 0;
    var yz = tab[0].length - 1;
    var val = '';
}
```

(HTML)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <title>karta</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="content">
        <p>Jesteś X.</p>
        <table border = '1px' width = '75px'>
            <tr>
                <td>.</td>
                <td>.</td>
                <td>.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>.</td>
                <td>.</td>
                <td>.</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>.</td>
                <td>.</td>
                <td>.</td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </div>
    <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="go()">Accept</a><br>
    <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="Right()">Right</a><br>
    <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="Left()">Left</a><br>
    <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="Up()">Up</a><br>
    <a id="myLink" href="#" onclick="Down()">Down</a>
    <script src = kod.js></script>
</body>
</html>
```

I found that to write table (I make 3x3 table and just write 'X' and 'O' in cells) I need to make something like function draw.

So it worked... first time. When I use this function again it just doesn't draw anything (I checked that tab value has changed), but `draw()` drew same thing or just did nothing. Of course I am opened for all ideas how way to display this table, but still want to know what is not working.

Probably good idea is to use same way as I made current table and add ID to all cells than add just values to those cells (but that is just some probably stupid idea from tired beginner, sorry for not checking it by myself but anyway I want to ask about this first thing so...).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I hade a guick look and i saw that that second time draw function is triggered `xz < tab.length` is always false. where `xz = 3` and `tab.length =3` also.
There you have the problem, so it never Enter the table draw operation.

Comment: Ty I am blind. Should I delete question?

Comment: Its upp to you.

Answer (score 1):

From a practical approach it does not seem like this is really a thing you would want to use JS for.

I would make some css classes for what a  element with X, O or nothing looks like.

Then store the state of who's turn it is in JS. When a user clicks on a  element add the appropriate class to the element for that turn.

You can also make like a win checker function to try and compute who won automatically

Comment: Whole program was created to learn how to display things, and I was just interested why I can't use this fuction again to draw table but with new values. I kown that there is more efective way to make it, but I wanted to train things like innerHTML, appendChild... I know it's too long for just quick test but I was having fun writing this so it end up that long, but when i will improve this code I will probably try UR way ty.